# How to make HTTP Patch request to raven db server using golang?

Tags: go, ravendb, ravendb-http

I have written the following code to add a title field to the document 1 in my raven database.

```
url := "http://localhost:8083/databases/drone/docs/1"
fmt.Println("URL:>", url)

var jsonStr = []byte(`{"title":"Buy cheese and bread for breakfast."}`)
req, _ := http.NewRequest("PATCH", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "myvalue")
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
```

I don't understand why it is not working? I am getting the following response Body which is not what I am expecting. I am expecting a success response.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Could not figure out what to do</h1>
    <p>Your request didn't match anything that Raven knows to do, sorry...</p>
</body>
```

Can someone please point out what am I missing in the above code?

Comment: I assume `curl -X POST -d '{"title": "Buy cheese and bread for breakfast."}' -H 'X-Custom-Header: myvalue' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8083/databases/drone/docs/1` works then?

Comment: If you want a PATCH request, why are you making a POST?

Comment: Ha, good catch @JimB (didn't pay enough attention to the title)

Comment: Sorry @JimB I was trying with post, get etc. I am getting same error for all these requests. I will edit the code :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For [**PATCH**](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.0/csharp/http-api/http-api-single#patch) request, you need to pass an array with patch commands (in json format) to execute.

To change the `title` attribute, it will look like:

```
var jsonStr = []byte(`[{"Type": "Set", "Name": "title", "Value": "Buy cheese and bread for breakfast."}]`)
```

Answer (score 3):

`PATCH` and `POST` are different http verbs.

I think you just need to change this;

```
 req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
```

to

```
 req, _ := http.NewRequest("PATCH", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
```

Or at least that is the first thing. Based on comments I would speculate the body of your request is also bad.

Comment: Using this code with a rails server I needed to include `req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")`

Comment: @RickSmith yeah the content-type header is going to be required more often than not. Checking your header is always worth while if an HTTP request is failing for unkown reasons.